# Insert extra columns with NULL values from one table to another table HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

Table1 have columns col1 , col2 ,col3 , col4 , col5

Table2 have columns col1 , col3 , col5

I want to insert rows from Table2 to Table1

But col2 , col4 should be NULL datatype after inserting into Table2

How can I do it in HIVE , Currently I am using Hortonworks 3.1 version

Answer (score 0):

You just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    select col1, null, col3, null, col5
    from table2;
```

Comment: @SanthoshChakka . . . What does "not working" mean?